# Python return code for os.system() and subprocess.call() command

Tags: python, windows, robocopy

I am running python on windows server.

I want the return code for os.system , so that i can check whether robocopy was successful or not.

```
a=os.system('robocopy \\\\aucb-net-01\\d$ \\\\nasc01\\rem\\aucb-net-01 /E /MIR')
```

will `"a"` have any value ? can i print it ? like this  print `("a",a)`

and then I can decide whether the robocopy was successful or not.

Also how can I run above robocopy with  subprocess.call()  command?  And also get the return code.

thanks everyone for reading my post.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide sample code of your attempt. Why do you need powershell for this?

Answer (score 2):

using os.system

```
import os
cmd = os.system('robocopy \\\\aucb-net-01\\d$ \\\\nasc01\\rem\\aucb-net-01 /E /MIR')
exit_code = os.WEXITSTATUS(cmd)
```

using subprocess

```
import subprocess
exit_code = subprocess.call('robocopy \\\\aucb-net-01\\d$ \\\\nasc01\\rem\\aucb-net-01 /E /MIR', shell=True)
```

Comment: also, i want to send email in the python script running on windows.

Comment: `os.WEXITSTATUS` isn't defined in Windows Python. Exit codes in Windows in general are 32-bit values. If it's not a generic success (0) or failure (1) code or custom application error code, then it could be a 16-bit Windows error code or even a 32-bit `HRESULT` or `NTSTATUS` code. The latter is usually only when the process fails to initialize for the given reason.

Comment: @user1602531 that is a separate issue. If you are having specific troubles ask another question on Stack Overflow

Comment: @eryksun Is there anything that can be used that is cross-platform compatible?

Comment: If you want a function for this on Windows, you could simply use `success = lambda x: x == 0`. Note that the non-Windows exit status handling in the subprocess module  (i.e. `Popen._handle_exitstatus`) first checks `os.WIFSIGNALED(sts)` (the signal status is in the low 8 bits), for which it uses `returncode = -os.WTERMSIG(sts)`, i.e. terminating the shell by a signal makes the exit code negative. With `os.system` on Unix (at least in my test on Linux), you'd also need `-os.WTERMSIG(sts)` to get the same exit code as subprocess when `os.WIFSIGNALED` is true.